# Modify plainnat.bst to not include "note"

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, natbib

I am using `natbib` with my thesis, and in particular I am using a self-modified version of `plainnat.bst` to always respect capitalization in titles.

Now, I'd like to make another modification: I **never** want the `note` entry to be printed, or, alternatively: **always** put the `note` entry on a new line in the reference.

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found that simply removing

```
new.block
note output
```

from the entry functions simply did the trick!